# SII Suministro Inmediato de información

Tags: java, webservice, aeat-sii

Estoy tratando de realizar un proyecto en Java para consumir los servicios web correspondientes al SII.

Ya tengo relleno (creo que correctamente) un objeto `SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas` con una factura de ejemplo, y también un objeto `X509Certificate con` los datos de un certificado obtenidos de un fichero .PFX.

En teoría sólo me queda enviar este objeto al servidor de pruebas y obtener la respuesta correspondiente, pero aquí me he quedado. No sé qué métodos tengo que utilizar.

He visto ejemplos de gente que lo ha logrado en .NET, pero no soy capaz en Java.

¿Alguien puede indicarme cómo tengo que proceder?

ACLARACIONES:

1. La pregunta está referida al nuevo Sistema de Suministro de Información del IVA que se va a implantar en España en Julio de 2017.
2. Sólo alguien que esté familiarizado con este sistema será capaz de solventar mi duda. Podría adjuntar el código que llevo escrito, pero sería largo y creo que nada aclaratorio.
3. En resumen, la cuestión es que se trata de crear un objeto, que básicamente es un array de facturas y enviarlas a un servidor mediante https. El objeto lo he creado, pero no sé cómo proceder para enviarlo al servidor (y recibir la respuesta), ya que no he visto ningún ejemplo en ningún lado que lo haga.
4. Insisto en que sólo podrán ayudarme personas que estén actualmente desarrollando soluciones para este problema.

Espero haber aclarado los requerimientos y gracias por contestar.

Comment: Hola Julian, bienvenido. ¿Por qué "no eres capaz en Java" ?  Has de mostrarnos el codigo que has intentado y los errores/problemas que te surgieron para que sobre ese codigo poder ayudarte. Asi sin más es muy amplio. Un saludo

Comment: Estamos hablando del Servicio Inpuestos Internos de Chile? O Es una coincidencia de nombres?

Comment: Julian deberias aceptar la respuesta de rsciriano o al menos decir algo al respecto (si te ha funcionado)

Answer (score 3):

Lo que necesitas es consumir los servicios web publicados por hacienda desde Java.

Para ello necesitas usar las definiciones de servicios `WDSL` proporcionadas por hacienda que tienes en [esta página](http://www.agenciatributaria.es/AEAT.internet/Inicio/Ayuda/Modelos__Procedimientos_y_Servicios/Ayuda_P_G417____IVA__Llevanza_de_libros_registro__SII_/Ayuda_tecnica/Informacion_tecnica_SII/WSDL_de_los_servicios_web/WSDL_de_los_servicios_web.shtml)

Con estas definiciones WDSL tienes que generar el cliente como indican en [este artículo](https://jalvarus.wordpress.com/2015/04/14/consumir-un-web-services-desde-java/)

1. Descargar el framework de CXF, tener la carpeta instalada en algún directorio.
2. Crear en SoapUi un nuevo proyecto para apuntar la url de la definición WDSL del servicio (esta sería para facturas Emitidas: http://www.agenciatributaria.es/static_files/AEAT/Contenidos_Comunes/La_Agencia_Tributaria/Modelos_y_formularios/Suministro_inmediato_informacion/FicherosSuministros/V_06/SuministroFactEmitidas.wsdl)
3. Verificar que tenemos los métodos del web services y probar con ellos.
4. Generar el código del cliente web services desde SoapUI.
5. Crear un proyecto en nuestro IDE de java preferido, copiar la carpeta generada en el paso anterior al nuevo proyecto (en la carpeta SRC de nuestro proyecto java).
6. Generar el código en java para consumir el Web Services.

> **Nota:** No estoy seguro de que la respuesta que te he proporcionado funcione por completo porque yo no trabajo con Java pero el procedimiento es muy similar en todas las plataformas *(bueno, en .NET es ultra sencillo, con solo agregar referencia a servicio Web lo tienes todo)*

**Actualización:** En [este artículo](http://www.imagineanddo.com/2011/10/java-ejemplo-de-como-consumir-un-web.html) hay otro ejemplo de como consumir un servicio web a partir de la definición `WDSL` cuyo procedimiento parece más sencillo (es muy similar a lo que hacemos en .NET)

Answer (score 0):

El código del cliente del webservice también lo puedes generar mediante la herramienta `wsimport` que se encuentra en la carpeta `$JDK/bin` de la siguiente manera:

```
wsimport -b bindings.xml -Xnocompile https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/fact/ws/SuministroFactEmitidas.wsdl
```

Donde el fichero `bindings.xml` contiene lo siguiente:

```
<jaxws:bindings xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws">
    <jaxws:enableWrapperStyle>false</jaxws:enableWrapperStyle>
</jaxws:bindings>
```

Una vez que tienes el código de cliente, para consumir los servicios debes autenticarte con el certificado electrónico de cliente. En Java lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");
keyStore.load(null, null);

KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
kmf.init(keyStore, null);

TLSClientParameters tlsParams = new TLSClientParameters();
tlsParams.setSecureSocketProtocol("TLS");
tlsParams.setKeyManagers(kmf.getKeyManagers());

SiiService service = new SiiService();
SiiSOAP soap = service.getSuministroFactEmitidasPruebas();
((HTTPConduit)ClientProxy.getClient(soap).getConduit()).setTlsClientParameters(tlsParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

Así funciona:

JDK 6.

Crear cliente sii para envío facturas y añadir certificado cliente

### El cliente lo he creado así:

sh /axis2-1.6.2/bin/wsdl2java.sh -uri http://www.agenciatributaria.es/static_files/AEAT/Contenidos_Comunes/La_Agencia_Tributaria/Modelos_y_formularios/Suministro_inmediato_informacion/FicherosSuministros/V_07/SuministroFactEmitidas.wsdl -p com.remote.sii.client.model -d xmlbeans -s

Te bajas axis2 y listo, tienes el script wsdl2java.sh para crear el cliente java.

Esto te crea una carpeta donde tienes un build.xml y todos los fuentes con ademas un build.xml(modificarlo para poner el nombre del jar resultante) que con ant te construye el jar con el cliente.

---

Añades el jar a tu proyecto y usas los servicios creados a partir del stub:

SiiServiceStub stub = new SiiServiceStub();

---

Integrar certificado en las llamadas:

URL jksurlClient = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("com/sii/xxxxx.jks");
  String jksClient = jksurlClient.getFile();
  System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore",jksClient);
  System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "XXXXX");

Y ya se puede usar el stub para realizar los envíos.

Notas:
Se ha de crear un almacén de claves(.jks) y añadir el .p12 del certificado(clave privada), importante que se use la misma clave para generar el almacén que la de la clave privada.